# Finding out the length of a cat6 cable

Tags: cables, test-equipment

I noticed this tester had precise length readings of short cables.
I decided to plug a very long cable (almost a full pack) and was surprised to see it still gives a reading. 232 meters:

[image: Fluke - Cable length without cap]

Adding the cap to the end of the cable, corrected the length shown by 2 meters:

[image: Fluke - Cable length with cap]

**How does it do that?**
**How reliable is it?**

Comment: How much is "almost a full pack"? We don't know where in the world you are located and "a full pack" means different things in different regions.

Comment: @DwayneReid Yeah, sorry about that - I thought it didn't matter since I have no idea how much cable was taken from it. It had originally 305m.

Comment: The full pack meaning a 1000ft/305m box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meter uses TDR, [Time-Domain Reflectometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometer) tests to determine the length.

> CableIQ™ Residential Qualifier: Graphically maps wiring systems and shows distance to faults with built-in **TDR**

From wiki:

> A TDR measures reflections along a conductor. In order to measure those reflections, the TDR will transmit an incident signal onto the conductor and listen for its reflections. If the conductor is of a uniform impedance and is properly terminated, then there will be no reflections and the remaining incident signal will be absorbed at the far-end by the termination. Instead, if there are impedance variations, then some of the incident signal will be reflected back to the source. A TDR is similar in principle to radar.

Essentially, taking the know, to spec characteristics of ethernet cabling, it sends a pulse down the wire, and listens for the reflection that is sent back. Depending on how long the pulse takes, it's shape, and other factors, it can accurately estimate the cable length.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9cP6w2odGUc relevant TDR video

Answer (score 1):

@DanielGomes it's worth noting that a TDR can be created with an oscilloscope and function generator. By displaying the waveform not only can the end reflections be seen. But even high impedance points like joins and or damage. (but of course you have to do the delay/distance calculations) A TDR can also be used for any consistant cable if the parameters are known. Eg Coax or even optical with the appropriate adapters.

In fact on optical cables they use freeze spray on the exterior to change the optical characteristics when trying to find the damaged point. Since cables can run for many km and are often buried, finding the exact spot involves a bit of guesswork, exposing the exterior cable, freezing the exposed part and retesting to see how close and in what direction the fault is.